# In Dart/Flutter , how to wait until this callback async completes?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

In flutter, I am using xml library to build xml

```
final builder = XmlBuilder();

builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');


  builder.element("resources",
      namespaces: {"http://schemas.example.com/settings": "settings"},
      nest: await  () async  { // wait until this completes 
        await Future.forEach<String?>(keys, (element) async {
          final transString = await sheet.values.rowByKey(element!);
         
          builder.element("product", attributes: {"name": element},
              nest: () {
            builder.text(transString![allCols.indexOf("tay")]);
          });

        });

      });

  print(builder.buildDocument().toXmlString()); // this reaches before nest: function completes
```

Now my problem is , in the  `builder.element(...)` function call , there is a callback `nest` which builds inner nodes of XML

Inside `nest` I am using Google Sheets library to read data from a Google Sheet and append it to XML

Since `sheet.values.rowByKey(..)` is a Future function , I need to `await` to get the value  and build the inner nodes

My problem is ,

after the line `builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');` , the execution directly comes to `print(builder.buildDocument().toXmlString())` before the nest's callback got executed

That is , the `builder.element (..)` executed with it's first 2 params  , but it skips to next line (print(..)) before the `nest` callback executed which is `async`

After this `print` , the block inside `nest` is executed !!!

So the print statements only print the XML with "< resources...>" tag , but not the inner tags

I tried putting await builder.element , but it's shows error since builder.element not return Future only void

So , how to make the builder.element to wait until it's `nest` block finishes execution and then proceeds to `print`

Comment: use `Completer` class

Comment: @pskink please explain

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html

Comment: @pskink yeah working.Thanks . But is there any way without using completer by make the block wait always ?

Comment: how is `nest` callback called?

Comment: @pskink When the  builder.element starts executing ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of method for await the data. I show you two method which i use mostly.

1. FutureBuilder:

   ```
        FutureBuilder(
           future:yourMethod(),
           builder:(context,snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              //Code Here
              return Container();
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        })
   ```

2.Using Method:

```
    Future<String> yourMethod() async{
    String data=await getDataFromApi();
    // Now you can use data variable inside code. its wait until data is assign
    return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `waiting` for your function to complete by putting `await` like this :

```
await builder.element("resources",
      namespaces: {"http://schemas.example.com/settings": "settings"},
      nest: await  () async  { // wait until this completes 
        await Future.forEach<String?>(keys, (element) async {
          final transString = await sheet.values.rowByKey(element!);
         
          builder.element("product", attributes: {"name": element},
              nest: () {
            builder.text(transString![allCols.indexOf("tay")]);
          });

        });

      });
```